# Chain methods in sub-class hierarchy to execute to get union of all methods execution in hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, decorator

lets consider a simplified version of my requirement

```
class Base:
    def __method(self):
        self.base = 'my-base'


class SubClass(Base):
    def __method(self):
        self.sub = 'my-sub'
```

I want my SubClass instance to contain both fields **base** and **sub**

Let's consider my attempt at the actual requirement

```
from configargparse import ArgParser


class BaseConf(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._parser = ArgParser()
        self.__add_arg()

    def pop(self, args):
        first_base = self.__class__.__bases__[0]
        if first_base is not object:
            super().__populate_arg(args) # <----------Compile failure------->
        self.__populate_arg(args)

    def __add_arg(self):
        self._parser.add_argument('--base', type=str, default='NA')

    def __populate_arg(self, args):
        self.base = args.base


class SubConf(BaseConf):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.__add_arg()

    def __add_arg(self):
        self._parser.add_argument('--sub', type=str, default='NA')

    def __populate_arg(self, args):
        self.sub = args.sub


conf = SubConf()
args, _ = conf._parser.parse_known_args()
conf.pop(args)
assert all(x in conf.__dict__ for x in ['base', 'sub'])
```

Ultimately I want the assert to condition to pass. I've mentioned the code line which is causing trouble by tagging it **Compile failure**.

I would also consider overhauling the overall approach and trying something better.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `super().__method()` will always fail because that's the whole point of using the name-mangling double underscore in `__method`. This ensures that this method is a private method, accessible only by that class itself (through normal means). Why are you trying to do this? Why not just have `Base.method()` and `SubClass.method()` call `super().method()`?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, the whole point of using name mangled `__private` methods is to ensure that attributes/methods are **private** -- they are restricted for use only by that class -- not it's subclasses. You can easily solve this by removing leading underscores, making a method `_protected` or `public`. For example:

```
class Base:
    def method(self):
        self.base = 'my-base'

class SubClass(Base):
    def method(self):
        self.sub = 'my-sub'
        super().method()
```

---

This is very much unadvised, but if you absolute *must must* get a private attribute from a base class, then you can use

```
class Base:
    def __method(self):
        self.base = 'my-base'

class SubClass(Base):
    def method(self):
        self.sub = 'my-sub'
        super()._Base__method()
```

but this only works if you know the name of the superclass. If you don't you have to get really hacky, something like

```
 class SubClass(Base):
    def method(self):
        self.sub = 'my-sub'
        sup = self.__class__.mro()[1].__name__
        getattr(super(), f'_{sup}__meth')()
```

Comment: To have a little more info about underscores in Python, take a look at [here](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/underscores-in-python)

Comment: I don't want to do `super().method()` because, for another implementation **AnotherSubClass(Base)**, I would have to call it explicitly again. That's what I am trying to address by using the `pop(self,args)` method. Also `__add_arg` is working as expected (getting both the methods executed for a subclass.).The name mangling helped me here, because with that `self.__add_arg` call in base-class would call the version from base-class for the subclass instance. If the name of the method was `add_arg()`, the call self.add_arg() would get **overridden** to use the sub-class version.

Comment: `pop(self,args)` is kind of common implementation across the full hierarchy which is trying to chain all the `__populate_args` methods in the class hierarchy. **Again, I want to chain and not override**.